# isChecked() behaviour exactly opposite in 2.3.6 & 4.2 android versions

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I am developing a simple Android app which creates a ListView with a checkbox as follows

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,results);
this.setListAdapter(listAdapter);
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                        long id) {
           CheckedTextView check = (CheckedTextView)view;
           //The below code needed for running on AVD version 4.2
           if(check.isChecked()) { 
                   // Checkbox checked do something 
            } 
           else { 
                    // Not checked. Do something 
            }
            /* Exact opposite need on Samsung phone running 2.3.6
            if(!check.isChecked()) {
                      // Checkbox checked do something
            }
            else {
             // Not checked. DO something
            } */
```

This is truly weird. How will the app ever be compatible with both version when they require completely opposite checks?

Please let me know how I can handle this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That it weird. Did you try running on 2.3.3/2.3.6 AVD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i know the problem, on newer frameworks the `onItemClick` call before the checkd attribute of the checkbox changed!

i check the checked state of my checkboxes in after item clicking (e.g. on activity close or save button click).

look at `list.getCheckedItemPositions()`...  it will return a `SparseBooleanArray` you can use!

EDIT: example

```
public class MyMultiChoiceActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ListView list = null;
    private boolean savedSelectionInvalid = true;
    private List<Integer> selectedIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.entry_data_multi_choice_filter);

        //initialize the list
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listAdapter = new MyListAdapterClass(this, R.layout.list_item_multiple_choice);
        list.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        //onclick on a item, set the selectaion as invalid
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                savedSelectionInvalid = true;
            }
        });

        list.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        //...
    }

    //...

    private void validateChecked() {
        if(savedSelectionInvalid == true) {
            SparseBooleanArray checkedItemlist = list.getCheckedItemPositions();
            selectedIds.clear();
            for (int i=0; i < checkedItemlist.size(); i++){

                if (checkedItemlist.valueAt(i)) {
                    selectedIds.add(a.keyAt(i));
                }
            }
            this.savedSelectionInvalid = false;
        }
    }

    //...

    //this method se
    private void saveAndClose() {
        validateChecked();

        //now you have the selectedIds filled with every checked item key!

        this.finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Karthik I plan to do that. A smaller difference though is that the placement of Cancel & Ok buttons are interchanged. This is harmless though.

Comment: Thanks.Yes I do use the SparseBooleanArray to process the checks. However as I have mentioned, I have to reverse the checks before processing on the AVD & my phone for it to work.

Comment: can you please elaborate on this. I checked on AVD 2.3.3 the behavior is still the opposite with the real device.

Comment: Thanks for your input. You are right there is an issue with onItemClick(). I removed the code from  and moved the processing to my 'delete' option. As you suggested I used the lv.getCheckedItemPosition() as follows                                       
   a = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();      
    for(int pos=0;pos<lv.getCount(); pos++){
          
     if(a.get(pos)){
  
      items.add(pos);
     }
    }                                                                                        and it works perfectly on the AVD and my phone. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 2):

The issue can be solved by checking the version of the device.

The documentation recommends you check `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` against the values in `Build.VERSION_CODES`.

Sample usage

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
 // only for android older than gingerbread
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html

(More like a hack than a solution though)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Is there a way to figure out at which version this behavior changed so that I can add a check? The check would use the reverse condition for larger versions (e.g. > 4.x)

Comment: Again this is probably a hack but you could just test behaviour on major OS revisions. Check on 2.3. If not that its probably got changed in 4.0

Comment: I built on 2.3.3. The behavior in the AVD(2.3.3) and device (2.3.6) are still the opposite. It is driving me crazy.  I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use something like this:

```
mFilterListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        ...
        SparseBooleanArray checkedItemlist = mFilterListView.getCheckedItemPositions();

        boolean checked = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < checkedItemlist.size(); i++) {
            if (checkedItemlist.keyAt(i) == position) {
            checked = checkedItemlist.valueAt(i);
        }
        ...
    }   
}
```

As a result you have a flag **checked**, which indicates what is the state of item after the click.